# Measure changes between the first and last point in a series of data

Tags: time-series, trend, robust

I'm unable to figure out what the common practice is for measuring changes across a selection of points in a time series, not just the difference of the first and last points.

For instance, let us assume the following set of points:

```
Month 1: 10 sales
Month 2: 50 sales
Month 3: 45 sales
Month 4: 55 sales
Month 5:  5 sales
```

Currently I'm trying to track the difference each month as I go along, which results in 5. This is because between each month, I add the cumulative difference. Month 1 and 2 differ by +40, month 2 and 3 differ by -5, etc.

Essentially, this means my result doesn't take into account any sudden spikes or dips within the numbers.

Ideally I'm looking for some sort of method which gives me a good indication of whether the trend has been mostly up or down, but hopefully not be too influenced by one-off spikes, as shown below:

```
Month 1: 10 sales
Month 2: 12 sales
Month 3: 90 sales
Month 4: 11 sales
Month 5:  9 sales
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea could be to form all the differences $d_t = x_{t+1}-x_t$ and then use some robust estimator of the mean. Some trimmed mean would avoid the spikes, the level of trimming should depend on how frequent are the spikes.

Others, with more time-series experience than me, could have better ideas ... this arXiv paper could be interesting: [RobustTrend: A Huber Loss with a Combined First and Second Order Difference Regularization for Time Series Trend Filtering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.03751)